# How would you create a safe int sum IList extension?

Tags: .net

I would like to create a safe sum extension method that would have the same syntax as the normal Sum.

This would be the syntax I'd like to use:

```
result = Allocations.SumIntSafe(all => all.Cost);
```

I use the `Int.Maxvalue` as a penalty value in my operations and two `Int.MaxValue` summed together returns a `Int.Maxvalue`.

This is my adding function:

```
public static int PenaltySum(int a, int b)
{
    return (int.MaxValue - a < b) ? int.MaxValue : a + b;
}
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

I would like to use this function on generic collections of objects that have the value to be summed in different properties:

ie

```
all.SumInt32Safe(all => all.cost);

days.SumInt32Safe(day => day.penalty);
```

Comment: Are you happy with IList<int> instead of non-generic IList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way of doing it:

```
public static int SumInt32Safe(this IList<int> source)
{
    long sum = source.Sum(x => (long) x);
    return (int) Math.Max(sum, (long) int.MaxValue);
}
```

Btw, PenaltySum fails IMO: PenaltySum(-1, 0) returns int.MaxValue.

EDIT: With the changed requirements, you just want:

```
public static int SumInt32Safe<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, int> selector)
{
    long sum = source.Sum(x => (long) selector(x));
    return (int) Math.Max(sum, (long) int.MaxValue);
}
```

Or call `source.Select(x => x.Cost).SumInt32Safe();` in the first place...

Comment: That is OK. Negative numbers are not allowed as penalties.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an extension method that will help you out: Aggregate

```
all.Aggregate(PenaltySum);
```

Comment: how will this deal with the fact that I need to sum over cost ?

Comment: You said you wanted a Sum extension method and that PenaltySum was your adding function.  This will run PenaltySum over all of the values and return the result